# Trying to select a random index from an array - always giving me last index of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

```
var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "1", "4", "9"]

var letter = letters[Math.floor(Math.random()*letters.length)]

random.addEventListener("click", function(){
quoteDisplay.textContent = letter
})
```

What am I doing wrong here? No matter what I put in my letters array, when I click the "random" button, it just returns the last index of the array every single time. I  want it to return a random index from the array, and I can't seem to figure out why it is not giving me a random index but rather just the last index. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you need to put your 'letter assignment' function inside the event listener.

```
var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "1", "4", "9"]


random.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var letter = letters[Math.floor(Math.random()*letters.length)]
    quoteDisplay.textContent = letter
})
```

This way, every time you click the button, you will run the `Math.random()` function again.

Comment: ahhh, I did not realize that. That makes sense. Thank you